# Installing ofBiz on Ubuntu 20.04, gradle wrapper failing

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, gradle-wrapper

I am trying to install Apache ofBiz on a remote server. I followed the instructions, install JDK, Java, gradle, I set the path to JAVA_HOME and all that...but when I run:

me# gradle wrapper

I get this:

[user@server]/downloads/apache-ofbiz-18.12.08# gradle wrapper
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/root/downloads/apache-ofbiz-18.12.08/build.gradle' line: 62
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'ofbiz'.

> Could not find method application() for arguments [build_9lkmuhzlimvrlzvo1mzh3ee76$_run_closure1@48f4ae7c] on root project 'ofbiz' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s

Folks, I used to set up Apache servers and build static websites back in the early 2000's. After the bubble popped, I became a diesel mechanic. I have been out of the game for a longer than some of you have been alive...take it easy on an old man, ok? I know a lot has changed. I'm kinda lost on this one. It LOOKS easy in ofBiz install guide, and some other websites with guides, but I'm obviously missing something somewhere.

Thanks in advance.

I tried the install instructions...but something is not right. I don't know if I missed something, or the install guide makes assumptions about the server that I'm not aware of. The server is a fresh VPS of Ubuntu  20.04. I also have the option of changing to FreeBSD and a few other flavors of Linux, if that might make this easier.